# History.js onpopstate?

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

I am trying to implement History.js after learning to use the History API. However my popstate isn't working anymore.

What is used in the History.js as the `onpopstate`? In the history API you use `onpopstate` with `event.state`.

What I need to know is what is used in History.js. Is it `window.onstatechange` and what does it return?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't tell it's from push or pop. This is by its design.
You should not do anything before push event. Instead, you should pass all your required data to the first parameter.

```
History.pushState(data,title,url)
```

Then retrieve data from onstatechange and do some actions.

Check this: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/47

Comment: As a note, data will get fully serialized every time, so do not include huge objects under data.

Comment: you're right, and it's a real pain in the ass. also see https://github.com/balupton/history.js/issues/96

Comment: The issue that @schellmax pointed to is now at https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/96

Answer (score 2):

The basic example says:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // code });
```

And [this gist](https://gist.github.com/854622) (for jQuery) uses:

```
$(window).bind('statechange',function(){ // code });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to use the event `window.statechange`, which has been invented by History.js as `window.popstate` is too general. You react to it by binding an event handler to it, typically like so:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
    var state = History.getState();
    // Your code goes here
});
```

Or you could use a router abstraction, which should be easier. I wrote one for example, called [StateRouter.js](https://github.com/aknuds1/staterouter.js). Some simple example code:

```
var router = new staterouter.Router();
// Configure routes
router
  .route('/', getHome)
  .route('/persons', getPersons)
  .route('/persons/:id', getPerson);
// Perform routing of the current state
router.perform();
// Navigate to the page of person 1
router.navigate('/persons/1');
```

I also have [a fiddle for demonstration purposes](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/K5vzt/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your tag body the next two events:

1. `onpopstate="(your code)"` --> for html5 browsers
2. `onhashchange="(your code)"` --> for html4 browsers

If you have any trouble like twice run your code, try build a function that asks if `pushState` is ready and use `onpopstate`. If not, in the other case, use `onhashchange`.

Comment: You might want to expand on this answer, provide actual code snippets for clarity.